# no puedo enviar mas de un mensaje porque se cuelga el cliente

Tags: python

no entiendo porque despues de enviar un mensaje no puedo enviar mas mensajes a mi servidor desde mi cliente

```
#servidor
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 6666

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print ("Socket Created")
sock.bind((host, port))
print ("socket bind complete")
sock.listen(1)
print ("socket now listening")

while 1:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    datos = conn.recv(4096)
    print(datos.decode('utf-8'))

    conn.send("hello".encode('UTF-8'))
```

el cliente se puede conectar al server, el mensaje del servidor llega al cliente solo despues de enviar el primer mensaje, al enviar un segundo mensaje desde el cliente no es posible

```
#cliente
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 6666

sock = socket.socket()

sock.connect((host, port))

while True:


  message = input("envia un mensaje")
  sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))


  datos = sock.recv(4096)
  print (datos.decode('utf-8'))

  if message == "quit":
    break
    print("bye")
    sock.close()
```

Comment: El cliente no debería llamar a sock.accept, entiendo que eso solo es en el servidor, en un socket a la escucha socket.bind.

Comment: entonces debo quitar socket.accept y remplazarlo con socket.bind, no entendi bien

Comment: eliminar conn, adrr = sock.accept(), para leer del socket sock.recv...

Comment: debo eliminar esa linea de mi cliente y por cual debo sostituirla para que pueda leer el mensaje que manda mi servidor

Comment: Eliminas conn, adrr = sock.accept(), cambiar conn.recv(4096) por sock.recv(4096)

Comment: pero si lo elimino la variable datos no seria valida y por lo tanto de que manera podria leer el mensaje que manda mi servidor

Comment: si no entendi mal elimino  conn, adrr = sock.accept() y cambio la linea conn.recv(4096 ) por sock.recv, (con esto la variable datos deja de existir)

Comment: cambiar datos = conn.recv(4096) por datos = sock.recv(4096)

Comment: ok ahora si me llega el mensaje pero en respuesta a mi primer mensaje, la idea era que apenas se conectara llegara el mensaje, sin embargo al segundo mensaje se congela y no me deja enviar mas mensajes mi cliente

Comment: steven estas muy  perdido con este tema. Las llamadas de lectura y envio son bloqueantes como te comente en tu otra pregunta. Tu cliente se queda esperando a recibir datos y mientras no reciba no deja hacer nada. Para recibir el mensaje de bienvenida pon esa linea y el print **antes** del while y en el servidor lo mismo con send. No obstante estas intentando enviar y recibir datos simultáneamente, para eso debes complicar mucho más el tema. Los socket son de bajo nivel y antes de meterte en ello deberias saber como funcionan teóricamente y leerte la documentación del módulo socket de python.

Comment: ya estudie la teoria, el problema es que hay muchisimos metodos y algunos hacen casi lo mismo con alguna variacion, en mi pregunta anterior me dijiste que para comunicar desde ambas partes era necesario usar los hilos y otra cosa mas que no recuerdo, sin embargo con ese modulo no tengo mucha familiaridad. retornando a mi codigo que puedo hacer para poder enviar multiples mensajes a mi servidor desde mi cliente

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas un ciclo infinito dentro del while que se encarga de buscar clientes para que una vez conectado uno se encargue de recibir los datos. El mensaje de bienvenida lo envias nada más conectase el cliente y antes de iniciar el ciclo para capturar los datos que envie el cliente.

En el cliente debes capturar este mensaje despues de la petición de conexión al servidor y antes de iniciar el ciclo para leer los datos con `input` y enviarlos:

Ejemplo de cliente y servidor con mensaje de bienvenida:

```
#cliente
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 6666

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((host, port))

#Aquí esperamos recibir el mensaje de bienvenida del servidor. 
data = sock.recv(1024)
print(data.decode('UTF-8'))

while True:
    message = input("Envia un mensaje:")
    sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
    if message == "quit":
        break

print("bye")
sock.close()
```

.

```
#servidor
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 6666
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print ("Socket Created")
sock.bind((host, port))
print ("socket bind complete")

sock.listen(1)

while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept() 
    try:
        print('Conexión con {}.'.format(addr))
        conn.send("Server: Hello client".encode('UTF-8'))
        while True:
            datos = conn.recv(1024)
            if datos:
                print('Recibido: {}'.format(datos.decode('UTF-8')))
            else:
                print('No más datos desde {}.'.format(addr))
                break     
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

Comment: no entiendo porque es necesario el segundo bucle anidado, tampoco porque usas el metodo format, es posible hacerlo sin ese metodo

Comment: Ya te lo he repetido varias veces en esta y en la otra pregunta: el primer ciclo está a la espera de buscar clientes, cuando uno se conecta se entra en el segundo que esta a la espera de recibir los mensajes de ese cliente. Si este ciclo no está solo recibes el primer mensaje del cliente, necesitas que esté constantemente mirando a ver si hay datos en el buffer de entrada no solo leerlo una vez. Por eso tu solo recibes un mensaje del cliente, lo aceptas, esperas un mensaje de el lo imprimes cuando llega y pasas a buscar nuevos clientes...