# Error de identación en estructura condicional

Tags: python

No entiendo porque me marca error de indentacion en mi condicional `else` si lo tengo indentado bien al mismo nivel quel `if`:

[image: screenshot del codigo]

El código se ve bien indentando en mi editor, como se puede ver en la captura anterior, pero en otro editor se nota el problema como puede verse a continuación:

```
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 6666

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print ("Socket Created")
sock.bind((host, port))
print ("socket bind complete")
sock.listen(1)
print ("socket now listening")

while 1:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    try:

       print('conexion con {}.'.format(addr))

       conn.send("server: Hello client".encode('UTF-8'))

       while True:

           datos = conn.recv(4096)
           if datos:
             print('recibido: {}'.format(datos.decode('utf-8')))

         else:
           print("no mas datos desde {}.".format(addr))
         break

    finally:
      conn.close()
```

Sin embargo si quito el `else`, el codigo se ejecuta, al primer mensaje que envio desde el cliente me responde el servidor, al segundo mensaje que mando desde el cliente se para el cliente y no me permite enviar mas mensajes. Agradeceria si me descubren el problema.

```
#cliente
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 6666

sock = socket.socket()

sock.connect((host, port))

while True:


  message = input("envia un mensaje")
  sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))


  datos = sock.recv(4096)
  print (datos.decode('utf-8'))

  if message == "quit":
    break
    print("bye")
    sock.close()
```

Answer (score 7):

La identación en Python debe ser consistente, debes usar la misma en todo el módulo. En tu código, para empezar, tienes niveles de identacion con 4 espacios, otras con 2 y otras con 3. Cada nivel de identación debería estar separado por cuatro espacios siempre, si seguimos las recomendaciones de [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation). Esto no da problemas en Python 3 siempre que las diferencias no se encuentren dentro de un mismo bloque de código. En Python 2 simplemente no puede pasar nunca o lanzará un error de identación.

Realmente lo que te está pasando es que **mezclas tabulaciones y espacios** al identar. Nunca hagas esto, la mayoría de los IDEs para Python si están bién configurados identan usando 4 espacios aunque tu pulses <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Visualmete puede verse igual cuatro espacios que una tabulación, pero el intérprete no analiza la sintaxis visualmente, lee bytes de un archivo y no es lo mismo `0x09` (tabulación en UTF-8) que `0x20` (espacio en UTF-8). Es muy común que aparezcan estos errores al copiar y pegar código de otros lados. En estos casos elimina las identaciones y identa de nuevo manteniendo la consistencia. El problema se encuentra localizado en las lineas:

```
datos = conn.recv(4096)
if datos:
  print('recibido: {}'.format(datos.decode('utf-8')))
```

Si mostramos los caracteres no imprimibles nos encontramos con:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde los puntos son espacios y las flecha tabulaciones. Esas tabulaciones no deben estar ahí.

Por otro lado, tienes un error en el `break`, debe ir dentro del `else` no fuera. Si va fuera solo leeras una vez del buffer porque el `break` interrumpe el ciclo en la primera iteración.

El código debe ser así:

```
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 6666

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print ("Socket Created")
sock.bind((host, port))
print ("socket bind complete")
sock.listen(1)
print ("socket now listening")

while 1:
    conn, addr = sock.accept() 
    try:
        print('conexion con {}.'.format(addr))
        conn.send("server: Hello client".encode('UTF-8'))
        while True:
            datos = conn.recv(16)
            if datos:
                print('recibido: {}'.format(datos.decode('UTF-8')))
            else:
                print('no mas datos desde {}.'.format(addr))
                break     
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

Y verse asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En Sublime Text puedes cambiar la configuración de las identaciones en <kbd>View</kbd> - <kbd>Indentation</kbd>. Debes seleccionar las casillas <kbd>Indent using Spaces</kbd> y <kbd>Tab Width: 4</kbd>. En el mismo menú puedes hacer click en <kbd>Convert indentation to spaces</kbd> para trasformar tus tabulaciones a espacios (verás como el código queda igual que en el editor de esta página) y después corriges la identación adecuadamente. Con esto el código debe funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: ok ahora no me da problemas con la indentacion sin embargo todavia no me deja enviar un segundo mensaje

Comment: @steven el servidor tal como está en mi respuesta es correcto y recibe tantos mensajes como le mandes, debes estar haciendo algo mal con el cliente....

Comment: acabo de subir el cliente

Comment: @steven repites los mismo errores que anteriormente, tu cliente se queda esperando recibir datos del servidor después de cada envio, datos que no llegan porque el servidor solo envia el mensaje de bienvenida justo al conectarse. La línea `sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))` y el `print` siguiente deben estar fuera del `while` para recibir el mensaje de bienvenida tal y como está en la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/62712/15089) a tu pregunta anterior. Repito, las llamadas son bloqueantes, si intentas leer del buffer pero no hay nada se queda esperando hasta que llegue algo.

Comment: ok ahora si puedo enviar mas mensajes, pero si quiero respoonder del servidor al cliente y añado un campo input pueden surgir problemas

Comment: Si el servidor envia siempre algo (por ejemplo una respuesta eco) después de que le llegen datos del cliente entonces si deberias incluir la línea dentro del `while` como la tienes. En este caso tienes que asegurarte que SIEMPRE que le llega un mensaje al servidor  este envia algo al cliente seguidamente, de lo contrario se quedará esperando como pasa ahora. La secuencia sería: servidor envia bienvenida-cliente envia mensaje-servidor envia respuesta-cliente envia mensaje-servidor envia respuesta... cliente se desconecta. Esta secuencia debe mantener siempre estrictamente este orden.

Comment: El servidor no esta pensado para eso, las entradas de los usuarios deberian ser dos clientes que se comunican mediante el servidor. Técnicamente es posible pero ya requieres del uso de hilos o corrutinas si deseas comunicación asíncrona (no sigue la pauta que explico antes, por ejemplo una parte envia mensajes seguidos y la otra responde cuando quiere o no responde como en un chat). Hablando de chat, los comentarios no deben usarse charlas largas, puedes usar el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) o crear preguntas nuevas. Saludos.

Comment: has pillado la idea, quiero un chat local sin embargo si debo usar hilos y otros modulos creo que me conformo con esto, aun asi si es que puedo enviar mensajes al servidor tambien podria enviar comandos

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes con que escribes espacios y tabs, lo que confunde al compilador. Cuando visualmente este bien identado el código pero no te compile, en Sublime haz: View->Identation->Convert Identation to Tabs

Comment: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) dice "Los espacios son preferidos para indentar". Lo mejor sería sólo utilizar Tabs cuando el código ya contenga tabs, pero de ser posible, hay que evitarlos.

Comment: Pero eso ya da igual, el problema que esta teniendo es que tiene mezclados los tabs y los espacios. Elige uno u otro pero hay que ser consistente. En eso basaba mi respuesta